# barbutton is not firing in ribbon control using devexpress

Tags: devexpress

```
private void barButtonItem4_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{ 
    RichEditControl richedit = e.Item.Tag as RichEditControl;
    DocumentRange[] foundRanges = richedit.Document.FindAll("Custom Action", SearchOptions.None);
    for (int i = 0; i < foundRanges.Length; i++)
    {
        richedit.Document.Selection = foundRanges[i];
        richedit.Cut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and don't forget to ask a question. What is your specific problem and the desired output?

Comment: I have created one windows application form and in that,I hav created ribbon control using devexpress and added barbutton for cut,copy,paste so when I click the bar button(such as cut,copy,paste),the button should fire for  the selected document.
I hav used richedit control,in that I have loaded docx file.